# Показать блок только по определённым дням недели и времени

Tags: javascript, php, css, дата, время

В коде PHP5.6 есть блок

```
<div>START</div>
```

но этот блок нужно показывать только по понедельникам и четвергам, и только с 6 утра до 10 утра (по времени сервера). Как такое осуществить?
Пока придумал только колхозный вариант:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Moscow");
$dayname = date('l');
$time = date("Hi");
if (($dayname == 'Monday' || $dayname == 'Thursday')&&($time >= 0600 and $time <= 1000)) {
echo '<div>START</div>';}
} else {
echo '<div>EXIT</div>';}}
```

Можно ли как-то более грамотно и красиво это сделать? И что бы пользователь время у себя не смог подкрутить.

Comment: Думаю timezone устанавливать лучше и перед первой датой.

Comment: Спасибо, а дата и время будут браться из сервера, на котором выполняется скрипт? Пользовательские дата и время не будут учитываться? Чтоб пользователь не мог изменить у себя дату и время и скрипт сработал бы

Comment: Да, php берет дату и время из системы на которой выполняется - то есть серверную.